# Выставить дату конца периода в виджете Date Range Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

Выставить дату конца периода по-умолчанию 1 месяц в виджете Date Range Picker.

сейчас у меня так:

```
$('.period').daterangepicker({
  singleDatePicker: true,
  minDate: moment().add(1, 'month'),
  locale: {
            format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'
        },
});
```

Период в месяц устанавливается, но в результате я не могу уменьшить этот период до 1 дня если захочу.

В общем **minDate** не подходит.

Помогите решить.

Answer (score 0):

`minDate` работает если в него прописать дату вида `MM/DD/YYYY`, следовательно сделайте так чтоб на выходе была дата в данном формате.

Comment: не совсем понимаю о чем вы. 
в общем решил проблему. minDay выставил сутки. 
а текущую дату + 1 месяц добавил из php в сам тег input

Comment: Это я и имел в виду.